# Download only the required part of a webpage on IMDB using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, imdb

I am trying to retrieve images of movies from IMDB by going through a csv file with movie names and downloading the movie cover pictures and storing it locally. Instead of downloading the entire webpage and then selecting the required part(image element).

Is there a way to just find the "get" request the browser sent to retrieve the image ?

I was able to get the Url but there does not seem to be a pattern so as to iterate over a loop and continuously download images.

This is the get request for toy story 1:

[image]

This is the get request for toy story 3:

[image]

I was able to remove all the characters after "@" and still get  the image as they are the sizing option for the image.

Comment: Can't you just get the image tags, iterate over them, extracting the url, then download all images from the urls you have gathered?

Comment: In that case too , I would be downloading the entire webpage initially right ?

Comment: Yes, the html part, not the other files (js, css, images, etc.) that a browser would normally do.

Comment: When a browser loads the IMDB page, it will fetch the html & all the linked content for it, i.e. the javascript, css, images and other media files that are linked in the html itself. If you are using python-requests, then that is a headless browser. It does not fetch the linked content, but only the actual html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OMDB API](http://www.omdbapi.com/). By querying that API, you get tons of information in a JSON response, including a link to its cover image. For example, searching for Toy Story:

> {"Title":"Toy Story",
>
> "Year":"1995",
>
> ...
>
> "Poster":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDU2ZWJlMjktMTRhMy00ZTA5LWEzNDgtYmNmZTEwZTViZWJkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDQ2OTk4MzI@._V1_SX300.jpg",
>
> ...
>
> "Response":"True"}

I've used it for my [Movie Indexer](https://github.com/bluemoon93/IMDBIndexer), albeit in Java, if you wanna check out how it works.

Comment: I will be iterating over a list of 9000 movies in a multithreaded program , will I be blocked from making too many requests in any case ?

Comment: Im not sure tbh. I dont think so, but its a matter of trying. 9000 requests isnt much for that API